# UDP activation over WAS - issues

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, udp, was

I refer the sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717041(v=vs.110).aspx

Upon compiling and executing the steps as listed, I start the activator using "Run As Administrator". Later I fire the client call, it reaches the server and I am getting the following error in event viewer.

> An error occurred while trying to read and instantiate the configured
>   ProcessHandlerType.
>
> Exception: System.ArgumentException
>
> Message: Unknown protocol ID 'net.udp'.
>
> StackTrace:    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.ProcessHost.StartProcessProtocolListenerChannel(String
>   protocolId, IListenerChannelCallback listenerChannelCallback)

Just before this message (the last step where I started by udp activator..) and the event viewer records the start by the following message

> Listener Adapter protocol 'net.udp' successfully connected to Windows
>   Process Activation Service.

I have checked the following.

1. Plain UDP sample console exe based UDP test working fine in the same environment (so no firewall ....etc)
2. I ensured the default website has all protocols in Bindings, and Enabled protocolos "http,net.udp"
3. The environment (win8EE) has frameworks till v4.5 but the default app pool used configured v4.0
4. All the projects are compiled for 4.0 and supported runtime correctly mentioned as v4.0 (also sku)

Let me know I need to check anything else.

Update:

Upon checking further the error messages were related to permissions (I don't alter the app pool permissions, but identity configured during the above process is current logged in user, which is stored in appHost config file, also current logged in user is part of administrators group) I guess,

Message 1:

> A listener channel for protocol 'net.udp' in worker process '6300'
>   serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' reported a listener channel
>   failure.  The data field contains the error number.

Message 2: (this is the last message) Source "User Profile Service"

> Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other
>   applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The
>   applications or services that hold your registry file may not function
>   properly afterwards.
>
> DETAIL -   4 user registry handles leaked from
>   \Registry\User\S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415:
>   Process 6300
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415
>   Process 6300
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415\Control
>   Panel\International Process 6300
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion Process 6300
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415\Software\Microsoft.NETFramework

Both two messages were pointing to same process which is 6300.

Comment: The runtime for 4.0 and 4.5 is 4.0, just as the runtime for 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 is 2.0.  MS doesn't always rev the CLR version when they release a new version of the framework.  Not an answer to your question, but you seemed surprised that there wasn't a 4.5 option for the App Pool, so I thought I'd give a little explanation.

Comment: I did not surprise, just to record what is there as it is mentioned, some time if you don't track the windows updates, we may not know what is actually installed :) changed

Comment: Try `soap.udp` instead of `net.udp` in the address.

Comment: Does changing to soap require different steps, as mentioned here ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751494.aspx

Comment: I don't think so - that link is talking about implementing a custom solution for UDP.  Although looking at the link you're using (in your question) I see now that it's built upon the link in your comment - I was assuming that you were using the new UDP support in 4.5.  Sorry about that. :(